# MVC Scaffolding Not Loading Models or Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a new project in which I've referenced a class library for the model creation. I've also added a connection string to a database that already contains the information I need to pull into my models and I have created and 'Area' for the applications config.

When I attempt to scaffold a controller from my 'brands' class which I've referenced, the Models drop down only contains the BundleConfig, RouteConfig etc. and not the models I'm looking for and the context drop down is empty even though it should contain the ApplicationContext that is generated when generating a new MVC project.

So far I've tried the folowing:

- Updating Visual Studio
- Uninstalling and Re-installing Entity Framework
  and MVC Scaffold
- Starting Visual Studio in safe mode
- Re-referencing the 'brands'

So now I'm not sure what could be causing the issue. Can anyone shed any light on this at all?

Comment: Haber you made a build?

Comment: Yeah I have - still no luck

Comment: Is your Context class public?

Comment: it is yeah - public <Context name>() : base("name=<Name>")

Comment: Not constructor, but is your class public, public class YourContext: DbContext

Comment: Both the constructor and the class are yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that you cannot reference a dll file and use scafolding. You have to import the project not the reference. This fixed the problem.